# Postsharp: Access already applied aspects from an Aspect

Tags: c#, postsharp, aspects

I have created a small hierarchy of Aspects. 
Example:

```
public abstract class MyBaseAspectAttribute : Aspect, IAspectProvider
{
...
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects( object targetElement )
    {
    }
...
}
```

I was wondering if there is any way, inside the ProvideAspects, to find out if and what other Aspects are already applied to the targetElement - and get a reference to the Aspect instance.

Something like

```
PostShart.GetAspects(targetElement).OfType<MyBaseAspectAttribute>();
```

(my intention: check if a certain aspect is already added and if yes, then modify it)

PS: I did solve my problem in another way, but I if this would be possible it would make for a more elegant and efficient solution than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aspect repository:

http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-40-Aspect-Repository
http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_iaspectrepositoryservice

If you want to modify the aspect instance, you need to store the instances in a dictionary stored in a static field. The dictionary can be populated from the aspect constructor so it not only covers the case of `IAspectProvider`, but also when the aspect is applied as a custom attribute.

Comment: Gael, would you mind being more specific on the reasons behind the static Dictionary? So if I just use GetAspectInstances(), find the instance I want, cast it of course, and then call some public method / property on it which does the "modification" (e.g. add a value to an internal list) - will this not work?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the GetAspectInstances() not returning the list of instances before the AspectDiscoveryCompleted event is raised?